# Restarting with new account on iOS/GameCenter

Tags: clash-of-clans

I downloaded Clash of Clans to my iPad (iOS 7) this past weekend and started playing.

Of course, after a couple of hours I realized I made some newbie mistakes that are fatal to my future success.  I wanted to restart, but it seems the only way to do so is to reset the device which I really would like to avoid.

After some Googling I tried the option of logging out of Game Center and logging in with a different Apple ID.  But, sadly, CoC re-launched back into the existing game.

Is there any way I can start over? Or at least start a new game under a different account on the same device?

Comment: Stupidly and cleverly SuperCell linked the game to a specific device. So even upon deletion of the game that old village your trying to get rid of will not go away. If you contact the developers directly they may be able to delete your village upon request.

Comment: I have gotten over 3000 gems from clearing obstacles. A new obstacle appears every 8 hours up to a limit of 40. The amount of gems given has recently been increased tremendously. Coupled with the new addition of gem boxes and your early gem losses should not be a problem. If you want to contribute to SuperCell's success, each gem is only worth one US penny ($0.01) so it won't break the bank to buy a few.

Answer (score 4):

At first, you must log out from your existing game center account "Before" you wipe all of your data. After you do that, you install the game and after you install it, play it. After you do all of that, you will be noticed to sign in to your game center id. You just use your game center id without having a new GC id.  After you sign in, you will be noticed again with another pop up saying ***do you want to reload your village at town hall level "X"?*** If you want to totally reset your village, just tap the no button. And if you want to reload it, just tap yes :) simple, right? And 1 more thing... don't use backed up data if you are still in the "New user" page, you must get it back "AFTER" your device already passes through the new setting ("New user" page) of your new device. (Back it up after you install clash of clans)

Comment: In iOS 10, there is no feature anymore to logout from the Game Center, because there is no Game Center app any more. So that doesn't seem to work anmore.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to start a new Clash Of Clans village is to restore your iPad to factory default as a new device, ***not from a backup.*** If you restore from a backup, it will not work.

See this [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414) page on how to do this.

Then you will need to create a new game center account. This is because your old game center account is tied to your old village.

Finally, you can download [Clash Of Clans](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/clash-of-clans/id529479190?mt=8), and start your new village. Make sure to choose a village name you like, as you can only change it once.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you have to factory restore your device in order to start over. I can't speak for Jailbreaking because I don't jailbreak my devices.

Some of the advice here doesn't work. You can't just delete the app and remove it from game center because once you re-install the game, it will still bring back your old game. This is because it's within your system file that appears to be saved in the ipad. Jailbroken device may have something that allows you to delete the files completely.

When you do a factory restore, Do NOT restore from back up as it will bring up your old game, so you have to set it up as a new device. This is the only option. Yes it is annoying, as some of you don't want to lose everything. But if you want to start over, then you have to sacrifice one thing or the other.

However, there is a way to get the new account and then get your back up so you don't lose other important stuff:

1. Back up your device.
2. Factory restore and select "Set up as New"
3. Install Clash of clans
4. You have to create a new game center account.
5. open CoC
6. Finish the tutorials.
7. Once the tutorials is finished and you created a in-game name, then perform another factory reset and this time "Restore from backup"
8. Once your restoration is complete, immediately go to game center and log out of your old one and log in with the new game center you just created.
9. Open CoC and it will detect that your new game.
10. Read the direction carefully and type "CONFIRM" Viola, you now have a new account and not lose your back up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're considering stupid mistakes but the game is pretty forgiving whatever you do.

All placed structures can be moved at any time by long-pressing them and dragging them to a new position and there aren't really any game breaking decisions you can take.  As long as you have resource buildings up and running (which you will do) then you can always make progress.

If you want to erase your entire map that is possible too from town hall level 4.  Tap the "village edit mode" button (hand with arrows in both directions*) and then click "remove all".  This resets your village back to a plain field but puts all your buildings into inventory so you can replace them in a new layout easily whilst not having to go through upgrading them all again.

*[image: clash of clans village edit mode icon]

Comment: If you use gems you're given in the beginning, it's impossible for you to get that back.

Comment: @SachinShekhar you can do this by clearing obstacles and complete challenges if you are looking to avoid paying.

Comment: It has limit...

Comment: yeah it's the gems lost on bad noob decisions early on that I would like to recover from...one really should be able to start over again with a clean slate.

Comment: Just keep playing, you'll get them back sooner or later through gem boxes and other things appearing on your map. I've bought 2 extra builders with my gems so far and I've never paid anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall the game and choose to remove all game data. If you re-install the game again you can play on your own account and you can start all over.

Comment: Nope, I tried that first (sorry I didn't mention it), but after the re-install, the game launched right back to the same spot where I was. Very sad.

Comment: In that case i'm afraid there is no other way. Indeed i found that syncing your device to itunes and resetting it to factory defaults works, but i understand that this is not a prefered way to achieve such a thing. Source : https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130317163432AANyqgd

Answer (score 0):

Remove your Clash of Clans from Game Center (Select the Clash of Clans icon and swipe to the left - and it will show the REMOVED action) and it will notify "Removed Data from Game Center'.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way to do this than jailbreaking or restoring. I have done it myself and actually I use it daily to switch Clash of Clans accounts on my iPod. Steps to creating a new account:

1. Make a new Gamecenter account that has not ever been linked to any other Clash of Clans account.
2. Borrow a family member's or friend's iPod or iPad or iPhone (but make sure they have never played and don't plan on playing Clash of Clans).
3. Log into the new Gamecenter account on the device you have borrowed.
4. Download Clash of Clans on the borrowed device.
5. Go through the tutorial of Clash of Clans on the borrowed device. After completing the tutorial, switch over to your personal iPad.
6. On your iPad, switch Gamecenter accounts in your iPad settings to the new one you just used on the borrowed device.
7. When you launch Clash of Clans on your iPad, it will ask you "Do you want to load Chief _____'s village with Town Hall level _? Warning: progress in the current game will be lost." Choose the "Load" option.
8. It will then ask you to type "CONFIRM" to confirm your selection.
9. After typing confirm, it will load the other Clash of Clans account!

If you ever want to get back to your first account, just repeat steps 6 through 9 with your old Gamecenter. Even though it says you will lose your progress, you actually will not.

If you would like me to provide screenshots of the process or explain more in depth how to do this process, please let me know I am happy to help.

Comment: The clincher here is the "borrow a family member's (device)". Effectively that device will never be able to play their own Clash of Clans - because it will be linked to your (new) account. Logging out of GameCenter on the borrowed device helps, of course.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I am adding the steps you should take if you have a JAIL BROKEN device. Assuming you have [cydia](http://pangu8.com/cydia/) and [iFile](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/eu.heinelt.ifile/) installed here is what you do to start over.

You need to create a NEW gamecenter account. A gamecenter account is merely an [Appleid](https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create), by the way. I recommend creating it online in a browser on a computer rather than on a device.

Sign OUT of the gamecenter account on the device.

1. Open iFile and navigate to /var/Keychains/
2. Click on keychain-2.db to open it in **sqlite3** viewer
3. Click on SQL (top left hand corner of the screen).
4. Using the search bar above search, enter the following and press Search:

   select * from genp where agrp like '%supercell%'
5. The above shows you what will be deleted. Next enter this

   delete from genp where agrp like '%supercell.magic%'
6. After pressing Search to do the deletion respring or reboot your device and open up clash of clans where you will find you are starting over from the beginning.

Play for a while then sign in to your new gamecenter account and you now have TWO games saved in TWO gamecenter accounts and you can switch back and forth between them, however beware that [things can go wrong](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185510/is-there-any-way-to-get-my-old-village-which-hasnt-used-game-center-onto-a-new?rq=1).

Note I *have* performed exactly these steps and they worked - though not in about a year. Most of my information came from [this YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guQWgS5cI5c).

Answer (score -3):

You have to restore your device unless you want to jailbreak your device, which is much more laborious and troublesome. I put together a guide last year and you'll have a new village with your phone and all your media  just as it was before in less than twenty minutes. You can see it here http://clashofclansblog.paulbrucesamson.com/2013/09/how-to-restart-your-clash-of-clans.html

Comment: Please summarize the relevant information from the link.  That will ensure your answer is still valid, even if the site goes down.  Besides, it saves readers a click.

Comment: And indeed the above link is broken. Server no longer available.