# How do I delete my clash of clans village and start over?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I started a few days ago but after reading around a few forums, I realize I could have done much better on my village.

So, how do I delete my clash of clans village and start over?  There does not appear to be any option in-game.

I have not linked it to any game center account if that helps.  I did see a warning somewhere saying you should link it to game center to avoid the risk of accidentally losing your data.  This could be quite useful considering that I do want to lose my data right now.

Comment: @JK01 what device are you using? I.e. Android or iOs

Answer (score 2):

One of the answers isn't correct. Deleting just the game and reinstalling the game won't do anything as it will still bring back your old game. Even logging out of game center and logging back on won't help.

The only way to do this is to do a factory restore and set up as a "NEW" device. Unless your have a jailbroken idevice then it may be possible if there is an app that let's you clear data within the system file for Coc. But i wouldn't risk it.

Comment: The app that will let you clear your data on a jailbroken iPhone is iFile and you use an SQL statement to delete the data. I will create a question and answer describing this process, as it's what I've done.

Comment: The description about how to use iFile on a jailbroken phone is [in this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/291494/139609)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If you open the game then click the `gears`. Then click `Help and support`, then scroll down to the section `Can I reset the game and start again from the beginning`.  It says you can't do it.

**EDIT:** According to [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GU049Jwqlgg), just create a new Google+ account and make a new base on that account while also keeping your old base.

**If you are on android, go to the apps in the settings, find Clash of Clans and tap 'Clear Data**

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to reset your village but this is what you could do:
 1. Log out of Game Center and Log in using another account
 2. Reinstall CoC
Then you should be starting with a new village
Hope I helped.

Comment: This will not create a new account. The old village will persist unless you factory-reset your device.

Answer (score 0):

To me, there would never be any reason to completely **delete** your village. You can really only improve your village through putting builder time into it, and you would lose all the time you spent so far if you were to delete your village.

Instead, just start focusing on the buildings that you want to improve, and the troops you want to level up. There really is no benefit to destroying your current village.

Comment: Sure it is... We have a level 2 account attached to an Google account and an none attached high level. Deleting the first would avoid recreating an new useless Google account.

Comment: Is "an none attached" supposed to be "a non-attached"? As in, you have a high level village on your device that is not attached to a Google account?

Answer (score 0):

Ok hopefully this works so delete the game then you will have to change your Game Center to another account log out of the one that you are currently in and log into another or create a new one then reinstall clash of clans hopefully this helps you!!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  See [user83189's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/178031/139609)

Answer (score -2):

Delete your Game And reinstall, if you however want to keep it as backup, I think you can add that account to another with a link device feature but I'm not certain

Comment: This won't work if it's linked to any accounts like Facebook and Google+.

Comment: this doesn't work.

Comment: -1: Even if you haven't linked your game to Facebook or Google+ this doesn't work.