# How do I unlink Clash of Clans from my iPad?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am really annoyed that it's not easier, but how do you unlink a device?

I got Clash of Clans on my iPod and I linked my village to my iPad but I don't want my iPod village on my iPad. How do I unlink clash of clans from my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

You can't because the link is permanent. This is noted when you link your device for the first time:

[image]

You can however start a new Clash of Clans village by following the instructions in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164343/restarting-with-new-account/169381#169381).

I also recommend you read [this post on the forums](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/305740-how-to-unlink-my-clash-of-clan-on-lost-phone?p=2170307&viewfull=1#post2170307) as it explains really well how the device linking works.