# Is there any way to get my old village which hasn't used Game Center onto a new iPhone?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have been playing Clash of Clans on my iPhone.  I am pretty far along but wasn't playing via Game Center (now I know I should have been).  Now I have gotten a new phone.  I am trying to get my old account onto my new phone, but it isn't working.  When I first launched Clash of Clans on the new phone, it automatically did so via Game Center but with a new village.  I can still launch the old village on my old phone and I have opened Game Center, but it only asks me if I want to restore settings to TH2.  Is there any way to get my old village to my new phone?

Comment: It sounds like you linked your Game Center account in the wrong order.  Apparently you were supposed to connect from your old device first.  The impression that I get is that you have to create a new Game Center account or contact Clash of Clans Player Support as described at https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/421502-I-ve-lost-my-village-Can-I-get-it-back-

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete COC on your new phone. Then delete the saved date in your Game Center. Connect COC from your old phone to Game Center. Then reinstall COC on your new phone and connect to Game Center.

You can also make a new Game Center account. Connect it to your old phone and save savegame. Then log in on your new device with your new Game Center account and restore the old savegame.