# Lost my data because of uninstalling the game

Tags: clash-of-clans

I uninstalled my Clash of Clans and now my data is being lost.  I have tried everything to recover it.  How can I recover my save data?

Comment: That's odd, according [to this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/164343/1721) uninstalling the game does not delete your game data. Did you do anything in addition to uninstalling the game?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't saved in the first place, most likely you will not be able to get it back. You can try contacting Supercell, but they make no guarantees that you will get your game data back. Next time, make sure to either back up your game to Game Center or any other backups you may have.

Comment: Supercell support is atrocious you will be lucky to even get a reply asking for more information.