# How do I delete a village?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'd like to remove the already started village because my son can't / won't stop playing it.

Congratulations to the developers on the success of game, but I need to kill the village in order to save my son from himself.

Comment: wouldn't uninstalling it nip it in the bud?  Also, i think this has been asked before: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164343/restarting-with-new-account

Comment: Well yes it's a bit like in this post. But without the part of restarting. Just stopping not starting over again. :-D Anyway, uninstalling should help: Maybe you can delete if from your phonefiles too. This should be ok, if your son isn't that old, that he knows how to restore it.